# sending ajax call to server in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am new to actionscript. I want to send request to server on button click and without refreshing the page.

For this I implemented :

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://hub.abc.com/social/chapterid=1234");
        var loader:URLLoader;
        loader = new URLLoader();

        try {
            loader.load(request);
        }
        catch (error:SecurityError)
        {
            trace("A SecurityError has occurred.");
        }
```

But when I see network logs in broswer it hits at url
http://hub.abc.com/loginregister.do not the url i send

And it hits http://hub.abc.com/crossdomain.xml that too two times. I dont know why??
Can anyone please tell why this is happening??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making a request to a remote server, Flash first needs to check the cross-domain policy file to see if requests from your domain is allowed. If you have access to the remote server, you can upload a crossdomain.xml file there to grant your application access. [More info here.](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html)

If you don't have access to the remote server you may have to set up some form of proxy (a service that *has* access to the data on the remote server and which can relay this to your application).

In terms of the request itself, it seems like the resource you're trying to access is behind some sort of login wall since your request was redirected to a login page. If so, you may need to look into if you are able to authenticate yourself before requesting the intended data. This may not always be possible.

If what you're trying to fetch is a straight web page, there might be a public API that you can use instead. That would provide a more reliable response with the data laid out in an easily parseable format.

Depending on the resource you're trying to load, it may also be a breach of the terms of use to scrape the website.